# Android: If a phone supports LTE or not?

Tags: android

Is there a way to programatically find out if a particular Android based phone(not-rooted) supports LTE or not?
I could not find any related info in the docs.

Any info would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK the framework only give access to higher level WiFi or mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not in the APIs so, officially the answer is no. I reverse engineered the first LTE phone and didn't find any thing I could use.

Answer (score 0):

Use CellInfoLTE to check for something like a cellID or signal strength

if it returns null, then it doesn't support LTE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a way!

Android Telephony manager helps you.

You would have to write a simple java code.

"tm.getNetworkType()" returns the network type.

For more info refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html